# Do we get a banner/theming? If so: when, and what's needed?

Tags: discussion

Since RCSE is no longer in beta, do we get a slightly less plain banner at some point? :)

Comment: What's wrong with a plain design? Well, of course beside it being even more plain. :))

Comment: The site title isn't even monospaced...

Comment: Oh, didn't know that that's important (after all, such is made on client side nowadays).

Comment: I'm foreseeing a huge fight as to whether it should be amber or green...

Comment: Green of course! Amber was late in the game. And all text will be limited to 24x80.

Comment: The site title needs to be in that 8x8 bitmapped font used by arcade games.

Answer (score 3):

Not really, no.

We *can* design our own: there's a [question](/q/96/278) for that, and also user3840170's [more recent version](/a/1077/278). That won't speed up us getting our own custom site design (if we ever do), and there's no guarantee they'll end up using it even if we *do* [make our own](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7955/43394).

There's a plan for “some lightweight customization for sites” to be available in the future, but that hasn't been programmed into the Stack Exchange engine yet. I have absolutely [no idea when this will happen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190736/308065), but if/when it does, we'll probably get a little aesthetic variation – though nothing fancy.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - not in the near future.

As part of the changes to the graduation process that have been going on for a few years now, site-specific themes are not being created.

The new generic site theme is an ongoing development.  We can only await developments.

Keep your eyes on the main SE Meta site for announcements but don't hold your breath.